# Find index of double number delimiter

Tags: java, android, comparative-review

I have a `String` with a `double` number. Unfortunately, the number is created on backends with different locals, so it could be both 101.02 and 101,02 (different delimiters). I need to get the position of this delimiter if it exists and get 0, if it is not.

I've come to two options:

```
int pos = amount.indexOf(',') == -1 ?
                (amount.indexOf('.') == -1 ? 0 : amount.indexOf('.'))
                : amount.indexOf(',');
```

Second option with the same logic but different style:

```
int pos = amount.indexOf(',');
if (pos == -1) pos = amount.indexOf('.');
if (pos == -1) pos = 0;
```

I do not need to have a `double` number from `String`, I just need the position of the delimiter to color the `String` (using the Android class `Spannable`).

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this goal? And which of these styles are better, in your opinion? Is there some way to use the `DecimalFormat` class to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problems with the first approach

> ```
> int pos = amount.indexOf(',') == -1 ?
>                 (amount.indexOf('.') == -1 ? 0 : amount.indexOf('.'))
>                 : amount.indexOf(',');
> ```

are that:

- It's not that easily readable; the ternary operator [has value when what is tested is simple enough](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/ternary-operator-considered-harmful). But when you start nesting them, it often degrades clarity.
- The index is calculated two times, one to test whether it is -1 or not, and the second time to return the value.

As such, the second approach

> ```
> int pos = amount.indexOf(',');
> if (pos == -1) pos = amount.indexOf('.');
> if (pos == -1) pos = 0;
> ```

is the most preferable between the two, mainly for clarity. You should consider putting that into a utility method.

There would be other approaches like using a regular expression, but another good one would to not traverse the string potentially 2 times, and instead of looking whether the string has a certain character, loop through each character and see if it is one of the potential delimiters. With Java 8, you could have

```
int pos = amount.chars().filter(c -> c == '.' || c == ',').findFirst().orElse(0);
```

And you could write explicitly the `for` loop for Java ≤ 7.

Final point: having a position of 0 when neither `,` nor `.` are present in the String can be confusing; 0 is a valid index value for a string, and it can imply that the delimiter was the first character of the string. If you consider `".25"` (that could be a valid representation of a double number, the 0 before being implied), the code would consider this as if having no delimiter.

Comment: By the way, is it really worth to "write my own bicycle" to use only one "for" cycle (in Android I can't use Java 8 to support old devices) instead of making two calls to indexOf()? It is front-end and there are at most 50 elements on one screen where it is needed to make such check.

Comment: @Gaket the cost of `indexOf` on a small set of small Strings is very low compared to operations that manipulate pixels on the screen, so I wouldn't bother. Just leave a comment that it might be optimized later if needed :)

Comment: The second option is better. I wouldn't optimize anything except, maybe, if you knew that one  source locale dominated the input. Then I'd check for that locales delimiter first.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to make it obvious that `pos` is getting assigned a value, one way or another.  To that end, a ternary expression would be good.

But the way you wrote your ternary condition is confusing.  Inverting the condition would make it more readable.

```
int pos = amount.indexOf(',') >= 0 ? amount.indexOf(',') :
          amount.indexOf('.') >= 0 ? amount.indexOf('.') : 0;
```

I wouldn't worry much about calling `.indexOf()` excessively.  These strings are short, and performance is not likely to be an issue.

By biggest concern, though, is why the **fallback value is 0**.  A result like that could indicate either an initial `.`, an initial `,`, or no decimal separator at all!

A word of caution: in some locales, the `,` or `.` could also be the thousands grouping separator, so there might not be a definitive way to know whether `"3,141"` should be interpreted as three thousand one hundred forty-one or as an approximation to π.